# Odoo Entreprise14 on kubernetes Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: kubernetes, odoo-14, odoo-enterprise

I've installed **odoo Entreprise 14** on kubernetes, when i login i see a blank page and a response from the server `404 (NOT FOUND) web.assets_frontend.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) web.assets_common_minimal_js.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) web.assets_frontend_minimal_js.js:1 Failed to load resource`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to set it up, or did this used to work? How did you deploy it/what did you do, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I already set it up and the app is working fine , i used the Entreprise code to build my costum docker image as there is no Docker image for entreprise edition , then i've migrated my DB SAAS to an RDS . This is what i did so far . When i login i see a blank page and the error described in my post from the browser consol .